# Trying to get iOS 4 iPod app on a jail broken iOS 5 iPad without totally downgrading

Tags: ios, jailbreak, music, ipad, ui

I'm one of the many haters of the new music app because of its useabiliyt. I have an iPad 2 with iOS 5.1 installed on it. Is there any way to download the old iPod app from iOS 4 onto my current device?

Comment: You might get more interest in your question if you consider accepting any answers of your previous questions...

Comment: Did the answer work? It *probably* will, but I'm a little skeptical, especially because Apple changed the way that iOS organizes its music from iOS 4 to 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very interesting issue. It **MAY** be possible, but I don't know. Here's how I would go about trying.

1. Jailbreak both devices
2. Install [OpenSSH](http://thebigboss.org/guides-iphone-ipod-ipad/install-and-use-ssh) on both devices
3. Find a SSH client for your computer (I like [Cyberduck](http://cyberduck.ch/))
4. SSH into the iOS 4 device, navigate to `/Applications`, look for the iPod app (I think in iOS4 it was `MobileMusic.app`...could be wrong though) and copy it to your computer.
5. SSH into the iOS 5 device, navigate to `/Applications`, and copy the `Music~iPhone.app` to your desktop (just to be safe and back it up)
6. Delete the Music app from the iOS 5 device
7. Copy the iOS 4 Music app to the `/Applications` folder of the iOS 5 device.

Let me know if that works.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry to disappoint you, but there is no way of just getting the Music app from another version of the iOS. If you are so concerned then please try the App store for Music player apps, i have used iAlbums, it has a very nice and slick UI. It uses the default music player's backend to play music, so you won't lose on any features.

If you are ready to do some experiment, then you need to build a custom firmware (cooking a rom) with new iOS and old Music app, non-advisable since you risk bricking the device.

Hope i made some sense.